# High reserved ram, nothing fixing it

Tags: windows-10, memory

specs are as follows:

A10-7850K, with apu disabled

Radeon Vega 64, severe bottleneck, i know.

ASUS A88X-PRO

GSKILL ripjawsX 8GB (2X4GB) Correct timings and down-clocked at 1600 mhz ddr3 sdram

Windows 10 pro 64 bit, wiped it twice to no avail.

pic of some useful info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kiohm.jpg
ill do anything to fix this, i already am severely limited by the cpu, it also came like this when it was delivered.

Comment: What happens with one DIMM?  Are the DIMMs placed for single or dual channel?  if you enable the APU can you adjust the amount of RAM assigned to it? Maybe its a bug, memory reserved even though disabled.

Comment: @essjae, 1 dimm will not boot, bios shows only half installed, but both modules are showing visible to the bios in spd information and under the half amount, if i enable the apu, it will reserve .1 to .2 gb of ram, and i can adjust it only enable and the value is only up to 2gb anyways.

Comment: heres a log that might be useful i think https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z6gkoDwZUW1PGbiq6da_B4KzH7XU5W5I

Comment: Could be a hardware issue, can you test with different RAM?  Or different MB?

Comment: “bios shows only half installed” - This information isn’t in the body of your question